# Javascript If Else nesting

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Hello here is my code :
    var one = 0;
    var two = 0;
    var three = 0;
    var free = 1;
    function open() {

```
    if ($('#one').is(':visible')) {
        one = 1;
    }
    else {
        one = 0;
        free = 1;
    }

    if ($('#two').is(':visible')) {
        two = 1;
    }
    else {
        two = 0;
        if (one == 1) {
            free = 2;
        }
    }

    if ($('#three').is(':visible')) {
        three = 1;
    }

    else {
        three = 0;
        if (one == 1 && two == 1) {
            free = 3;
        }

    }
}
```

and then in the HTML part

```
<body onload="javascript:window.setInterval('open()', 1000)">
```

Now the layers one two and three are hidden by default. Now the problem is, at first the HTML output ( in Layer 7) is 1 (value of free) . But after one second it changes to 2. Shouldn't it remain the same? This is as all the layers have the same visibility(hidden) at each point in time...

Comment: I'm a little confused, what exactly are you trying to do with your code?

Comment: The code is just to see free layers(in terms of visibility) in the order of precedence 1>2>3

Comment: Can you please make your point clearer? Like, what is not and what it should be.

Comment: Do you have some code which changes the visibility? And I have to say: this makes no sense in my point of view. I still don't know where the use of this is.

Comment: I'm trying to make a program which shows the user which layer is hidden. And in the order of preference 1>2>3. 
Say layer 1 is hidden,layer 2 is hidden,layer 3 is hidden
then free=1
if layer 1 is visible layer 2 is hidden and layer 3 is hidden
then free=2
if layer 1 and layer 2 are visible and 3 is hidden
then free=3
and this is just to test my logic,i'm an amateur so i want to change visibility of layers manually and see if the logic works

Comment: can your logic be said like free = visible layer + 1

Comment: Not exactly. If layer two is visible,and layer one is hidden,it gets preference and hence free=1; as per the if statements in the above code. The problem that i'm facing is even when i change visibility settings of layers, free seems to be 1,irrespective of any changes.

Also,when i changed "one" and "two" to visible and three to hidden and tried to output the value of "three" it said 1,whereas it should be zero.So that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

give a class ('layers' for example) to each layer in order to collect them all together. Then loop them to find the first non visible and get the id.

```
var free = undefined;

$('.layers').each(function()
{
    if(!$(this).is(':visible'))
    {
        free = $(this).attr('id');
        break;
    }
});

if(free != undefined)
    alert('layer '+free+' is free');
else
    alert('there are no free layers');
```

Comment: Your answer seems fine.But sir, I intend to know what is wrong with my logic 

Thanks for your reply

Comment: it is not scalable, what if you got 15 layers?

Comment: Well,what i intend to achieve is show the *smallest* (in terms on layer number) layer which is hidden. I don't see anything logically wrong with my code

Comment: yes,but the statement   if ($('#three').is(':visible')) {
        three = 1;
    }

    else {
        three = 0;
        if (one == 1 && two == 1) {
            free = 3;
        }
doesn't seem to be working.Even though,layer "three" is hidden,the three=1; as per an alert

Comment: the main problem is that the if() statements aren't working. 
can i post the code somewhere ?

Comment: just post it here if it is not that heavy

Comment: <style type="text/css">
<!--
#one {
    visibility:visible;
 position:absolute;
 width:178px;
 height:308px;
 z-index:15;
 left: 744px;
 top: 117px;
}
#two {
    visibility:hidden;
 position:absolute;
 width:184px;
 height:313px;
 z-index:16;
 left: 453px;
 top: 117px;
}
#three {
visibility:hidden;
 position:absolute;
 width:216px;
 height:333px;
 z-index:18;
 left: 205px;
 top: 126px;
}
--></style>
<div id="three"></div>
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>

Comment: try to use display:none instead of visibility:hidden

Comment: for me it works in this way: put your function into a <script> tag. after your function, into the same tag, put this line: $(document).ready(function(){setInterval('open()', 1000);}); this way alert(free) alway show 1 to me